# jQuery on change using a select dropdown with ajax search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Firstly, here is my code:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#search_dropdown").on('change', function() {
        ajax_search();
    });

});

function ajax_search(){
    var search_this = $("#search_dropdown").val();
        $.post("../includes/db-search-properties.php", {searchit : search_this}, function(data){
        $("#display_results").html(data);
    });
}
</script>
```

What I am trying to achieve here is quite simple. I have a select dropdown with a list of clients. On click, the select changes the data table (called #display_results) without the need of pressing a button and that is why the change function is used.

This works, how ever you can only click the select dropdown twice and then it will not drop down again unless the page is refreshed. The event also causes my other jQuery events to break (such as my menu accordion to go up and down repeatedly) and I don't know how to tell this script to only focus on the task at hand.

Even though i've removed the login script, you can view the errors via this link:

https://www.summersproperty.com/dashboard3/directory/search-properties.php

Click the drop down on the right a few times and it will stop working, click the navigation menu items afterwards and they will bounce.

Comment: Is the `#search_dropdown` contained within `#display_results`?

Comment: No it is not, #display_results at the bottom of the page

Comment: In which case what you have should work absolutely fine. All I can suggest is that you check the console for errors when the select stops working.

Comment: There are no errors being generated in the console. This is why I find it most odd?

Comment: The only warning it displays is, "Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience."

Comment: In that case you're using `async:false` somewhere and should remove it. Thats not the cause of your problem though

Answer (score 0):

I would try stopping the event from propagating further.  Like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#search_dropdown").on('change', function(e) {
        ajax_search();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

[Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

Comment: Unfortunately this did nothing to resolve the issues

Answer (score 0):

It does appear after much trial and error a bug with Chrome, as it works wonders in all other browsers but stops after a few clicks in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#search_dropdown").on('change', function() {
     var search_this = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
     if(search_this !=''){
        $.post("../includes/db-search-properties.php", {searchit :    search_this}, function(data){
          $("#display_results").html(data);
        });
     }
     else{ console.log("no value found"); }
    return false; # optional
  });

});
```

Have you tried this ?  passing the value of current selection to your ajax call ?

for running example [check this](http://code.runnable.com/Ue9c4krQF7VjAAAP/how-to-get-selected-option-using-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for the cleaner code. It works in all other browsers, including the iPad Chrome, but bugs out on the desktop Chrome on my Mac. A workaround is unknown.

Comment: can you provide any sample error that chrome is generating ?  or any way to access the page you are having error with?

Comment: try this ` if(search_this  != ''){do search} else{no values found} `

Comment: I think my jQuery scripts are conflicting with one another